# Get either only Base or Child class objects in TPT Database

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

I have designed a EF 6 TPT Database. I created a type A and B, the latter inheriting from the former. What I don't yet fully understand is how do you query objects of ONLY either Type A or B? For example:

```
//When I need List<A>; works fine so far
return _db.ASet.Where(m => !(m is B)).ToList();

//When I need List<B>
_db.ASet.Where(m => !(m is A)).ToList();
```

The second code line is where my problem is. I get a `List<A>` as return type, but I need `List<B>`. I tried using `Cast<B>()`, but then I get an error that A cannot be cast to B.

```
LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

On a side note, is this even right what I'm doing? I saw this solution on a couple of answers here, but I haven't really found anything on MSDN so I'm not quite sure if this is the recommended way.

EDIT: From what I understand, I need to have a base class which I won't instantiate and have `A` and `B` derive from that base class. Is this right?

Answer (score 3):

The "**OfType**" method is what you are looking for.

```
// When I need List<A>; works fine so far
return _db.ASet.OfType<A>().ToList();

// When I need List<B>
_db.ASet.OfType<B>().ToList();
```

**Edit**

If B:A and need all entities from A excluding entities from B then you can use **Except** method

```
_db.ASet.Except(_db.ASet.OfType<B>()).ToList();
```

Comment: When I use OfType<A>(), I also get all instances of B even though I only want A. I assume this is because all B are also A.

Comment: I didn't test this, I did something else before you edited your answer. I just inherit both A and B from a common base entity so when I use OfType<A>() or OfType<B>(), it works flawlessly. the only downside to this approach is that A is essentially empty, it just references the Id from the base entity which holds the fields that define A. but it gives me much more convenience when selecting either A or B or both.

Comment: Good job ;) This is exactly how I though you have coded your inheritance at first.

Comment: 8 Years later, this helped solve the same mapping pattern in EF Core 8.  I had some issues because my initial implementation was `A:B` and didn't fully read the caveat of `ABase:A`, `ABase:B`.  This will only work correctly if you introduce an `ABase` from which `A` and `B` inherit.